# Update Boolean if statements every frame

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to do a timer if a collectible ring vanishes and is transparent.

My question is that it is only playing the boolean if statement in fixedupdate once? Do I need to change the Gameobject that the script is attached on or do I need to put my script on something that isn't going to be IsActive(false)?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RingScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("How long it will take that the ring is active again")]
    public float standardtimer;
    public float timer;
    private int uiTimer;

    [Header("The text and GameObject that will show you the time how long it takes to respawn")]
    public Text timertext;
    public GameObject timerobject;
    public GameObject thisRing;

    [Header("How many Forestgems you get")]
    public int ForestGemCount;
    public bool starttimer = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        timer = standardtimer;
        timerobject.SetActive(false);
        thisRing.SetActive(true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        uiTimer = (int)timer;
        timertext.text = uiTimer.ToString();

        if (starttimer == true)
        {
            timer -= Time.deltaTime;
            GemScript.ForestGems += ForestGemCount;
            timerobject.SetActive(true);
            thisRing.SetActive(false);
            if (timer <= 0.1f)
            {
                timer = standardtimer;
                timerobject.SetActive(false);
                thisRing.SetActive(true);
                starttimer = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            starttimer = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where and to what value is your variable `public float standardtimer` initialized?

Comment: and well it is executed everytime you set the `starttimer ` is set to `true` ... and it is set to true in the `OnTriggerenter` .. and that seems to be failing ... can you confirm that the line is reached at all? Maybe your Player isn't tagged correctly? and then yes if the gameobject this script is attached to is set to inactive it won't happen anymore ... so maybe you should attach it to another object in such case

Comment: @Bobbey In Unity itself so I can just adjust the variable how I like for each ring to set how many seconds it needs.

Comment: @derHugo I already checked it with Debug.Log before I asked the question and it was that the gameobject does not do anything if it is attached on smth so thanks!